# Comments in note board webpart disappeared after the migration

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

We moved a site collection to a new web application in the same farm and performed a version upgrade from sp2013 to sp2019. The site collection url has been changed

- from: http://oldwebapplication.com/sites/name
- to: http://newwebapplication.com/sites/name

Technically we dismounted the content db, then mounted it into the new web application and updated the site.

But the comments in the note board webpart, so called “social comments“, are stored in the user profile service database.

If you take a closer look at the table “dbo.socialcomments”, you will notice that there’s the url id column.

[image]

In order to get the comments back I could replace the old url id with the new one but I don’t know how to do

I followed [this link](https://spcaroline.wordpress.com/2016/02/05/sp2013-migrate-noteboard-social-comments-to-different-url/)
but doesn't work because Microsoft blocked all commands PowerShell of Tag & Note unfortunately.

If you know any solution based on SQL I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the Content DB from SQL is not supported in SharePoint.  You can do it, but Microsoft won't support it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply